# How to evaluate n in nCr when nCr and r known?

Tags: combinatorics, integer-programming

Today i was solving a programming problem and got stuck at this position.

Value of nCr is given where r = floor((n+1)/2). We will have to find the value of n ?

Help, please.

Comment: If $n$ is an integer (so that $n$ choose $r$ makes sense) then doesn't $r = \lfloor n + 1/2 \rfloor$ imply $n=r$?

Comment: No, the value of r = (n/2) when n is even
else r = (n+1)/2

Comment: In this case, you should probably say floor((n+1)/2) to be clear.

Further, are you saying that $r$ and $nCr$ are known, and that it is also known that $r =$ floor$((n+1)/2)$?

Comment: Yes nCr is known and r is known only in term of n.

Comment: If the numerical value of $r = \displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor$ is known, don't we already know that $n$ is either $2r$ or $2r+1$? Then, since $\binom{2r}{r}$ is always an even number, we can tell that it must be the case that $n = 2r+1$ if the given value of $\binom{n}{r}$ is odd. The question of whether the _given_ odd value of $\binom{n}{r}$ actually _equals_ $\binom{2r+1}{r}$ (or the problem-setter just put down an odd number and claimed that it is $\binom{n}{r}$ for the given $r$) is a different matter.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate : I all ready mentioned in my last comment that value of r known in term of n only. It's numerical value is unknown.

Comment: @Shravan40  Your problem states in the second sentence, "Value of nCr and r given." What does this mean? Would you please consider **editing** your problem to specify **clearly** in the **problem itself** what is known and what is unknown?

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate , I edited my question as you suggested. If there is still something not clear please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is even, we have the [central binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) $m=_{2r}C_r=\frac {(2r)!}{(r!)^2}\approx \frac {4^r}{\sqrt {\pi r}}$ so given $m$ we can take $r_0=\frac 12\log_2 m$ (which ignores the denominator), $r_{1}=r_0+\frac 14 \log_2(\pi r_0)$ (which adds more factors to account for the denominator).  Round up.  Check if it fits.  For example $m=1.3784E11, r_0=18.50214, r_1=19.9672, r=20$ is correct.  This will fail only if $r$ is very large so the change in the denominator from the first to second iteration is so large you need another factor of $4$ or two.

If $n$ is odd, we have $m=_{2r-1}C_r$  We can make use of the above by calculating $m'=_{2r}C_r=2m$ (Can you prove this?)  Find $r$ as above for $m'$.  See if it fits.